# $\sum_{1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{((n-1)x+1)(nx+1)}$ converges uniformly on $[1,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, sequence-of-function

My Attempt:
There is no dought that $$\sum_{1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{((n-1)x+1)(xn+1)}$$ converges pointwise 
 on $[1,\infty)$
But What's about uniform convergence and uniform limit of sequence $$< \frac{1}{((n-1)x+1)(xn+1)}>$$
on $[1,\infty)$

Comment: Its bit confusing

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the series with $\sum \frac 1 {((n-1)+1) (n+1)}$ which is convergent. By M-test the series is uniformly convergent.